# .NET/SVN : Build project using pre-commit hook

Tags: .net, svn, cruisecontrol.net

Novice question:

Is it possible to build my project (using BuildEngine or so) if I write a pre-commit hook in C#? What I want to do is, build the project upon commit on my dev server and accept the transaction if build succeeds. Is it even possible? If so some hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is :
- hard to do
- awkward

**1. Hard to do**

Your cc .net project is linked to a source control server (here svn). If you want to force a ccnet project in a precommit hook (which you can do by calling `ccnet.exe -c configfile.config -p "Project Name"` ), you will need to get the source you want to build against and in your case these are not the latests. One solution may be to commit to a branch and then make a cc .net project which would merge the branch into the trunk upon a successful build.

**2. Awkward**

A source control repository is always the code reference, what you commit MUST BE tested and correct. CI is here to check the repository integrity, do additionnal tests and automatic deployments. Thus, there can be commits that break the build but they must be exceptions, validating the build in pre-commit is overkill.

That's why I would recommend that you don't use a CI tool for your hook and that you use one "normally" to tests your builds (your builds would not be broken very often, but the functionnal tests can be wrong).